# enumitem & cref: referencing different exercises with cref for different chapters

Tags: hyperref, enumitem, cleveref, scrbook

I am using `scrbook` along with `enumitem` for exercises and `cref` for cross referencing. In my style file, I have set the following new list

```
% Rename enumerate from item to exercise                                        
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{75}
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\arabic*.}
% adjust cref for label names                                                   
\crefname{exercisei}{exercise}{exercise}
\Crefname{exercisei}{Exercise}{exercise}
```

In my main document, I using `\input` for the chapters. I have one issue and one question. The issue is with referencing nested `exercises`. Consider the following example

```
\begin{exercise}
\item
question 1
\begin{exercise}[label = (\alph*), ref=\theenumi{} (\alph*)]
\item
\label{ch21a}
sub question a
\item
From \cref{ch21a}, we have ...
\end{exercise}
\end{exercise}
```

Instead of saying exercise 1 (a) or (b) or whatever letter at the time, it produces

[image]

but a non-nested `exercise` works correctly. I would guess I am missing something in the defining the `newlist` but now sure what that would be.

That was my issue. My question is if I cross reference across chapters, how can I have the reference read `exercise 10, chapter 1`? That is, if I reference in chapter 2 exercise 10, I would like the reader to aware that the link will take them chapter one. Currently, if I reference in another chapter, it simply reads `exercise 10`. Can this be accomplished?

---

### **MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
% Rename enumerate from item to exercise
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{75}
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\arabic*.}
% adjust cref for label names                                                   
\crefname{exercisei}{exercise}{exercise}
\Crefname{exercisei}{Exercise}{exercise}
\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\begin{exercise}
\item
q1
\begin{exercise}[label = (\alph*), ref = \theenumi{} (\alph*)]
\item
\label{ch11a}
\item
\Cref{ch11a}
\end{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\chapter{two}
\begin{exercise}
\item
\Cref{ch11a}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code you get a warning like

```
LaTeX Warning: cref reference format for label type `exerciseii'
undefined on input line 24.
```

so you need to provide definitions for `exerciseii`; also, you need to prepend the `exercisei` counter for cross referencing, instead of `enumi`; something like

```
ref=\arabic{exercisei}(\alph*)
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

% Rename enumerate from item to exercise                                        
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{75}
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\arabic*.}
% adjust cref for label names                                                   
\crefname{exercisei}{exercise}{exercise}
\Crefname{exercisei}{Exercise}{exercise}
\crefname{exerciseii}{exercise}{exercise}
\Crefname{exerciseii}{Exercise}{exercise}

\begin{document}    

\chapter{Test chapter}
\begin{exercise}
\item question 1
\begin{exercise}[label = (\alph*), ref=\arabic{exercisei}(\alph*)]
\item
\label{ch21a}
sub question a
\item
From \cref{ch21a}, we have ...
\end{exercise}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

To add the chapter number to the cross.reference, label the chapters and use those labels; as in

```
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\label{cha:testa}
\begin{exercise}
\item question 1
\begin{exercise}[label = (\alph*), ref=\arabic{exercisei}(\alph*)]
\item
\label{ch21a}
sub question a
\item
sub question b
\end{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\label{cha:testb}
From \cref{ch21a}~\cref{cha:testa}, we have ...
```

You could define a command for this:

```
\newcommand\chapref[#2]{\cref{#1}, \cref{#2},}
```

and then

```
\chapref{ch21a}{cha:testa}
```

Comment: Emacs wasn't issuing a warning at all. This takes care of the issue. Any idea on the question posed as well?

Comment: @dustin please see my updated answer. I added a remark about the `ref=` part in  your settings and also proposed a possible solution to add the chapter to the cross reference.